# Merge series and recognize end of it - AWK

Tags: awk, merge

could you help me please merge rows by coordinates in column $2. There are series of coordinates growing by one. I wan to output f.e. : 1st row merge to 4th row 9079811-9079814 and after that there is no series so merge it to another row etc.. for 3rd column in input I would like to count average.

I wrote some script, but this script merge all rows from first coordinate to last coordinate. no condition to series.

```
 awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" '{print $2,$4,$3,$1}' input | awk '!x[$2]{x[$2]=$1}y[$2]<$1{y[$2]=$1;}x[$2]>$1{x[$2]=$1} {sum+=$3} END{for(i in y)print $1,x[i],y[i],sum/NR,i}' | sort -V -k1,1 > output
```

INPUT:

```
chr12   9079811 29  A2M
chr12   9079812 29  A2M
chr12   9079813 29  A2M
chr12   9079814 28  A2M
chr12   9091202 5   A2M
chr12   9091203 5   A2M
chr12   9091204 5   A2M
chr12   9091390 15  A2M
chr12   9091391 15  A2M
chr12   9091392 13  A2M
```

OUTPUT:

```
chr12  9079811  9079814 28.75 A2M
chr12  9091202  9091204 5     A2M
chr12  9091390  9091392 14.3  A2M
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 's{ 
         if ($2-prev == 1) { sum += $3; c++; prev=$2 }
         else { print $1, s, prev, sum/c, $4; s=sum=c=0 }
     }
     !s{ s=prev=$2; sum=$3; c++ }
     END{ print $1, s, prev, sum/c, $4 }' file
```

- `s` - variable pointing to actively processed series; contains the starting element of a series(for ex. `9079811`)
- `prev` - holds each previous item of the processed series

The output:

```
chr12 9079811 9079814 28.75 A2M
chr12 9091202 9091204 5 A2M
chr12 9091390 9091392 14.3333 A2M
```

Comment: Nice, I was working on something similar! You can drop the `next` from the end of the `!s` action block.

Comment: Great job, prev and !s are really new for me. Thank you for skills and for help.

Comment: @Vonton - `prev` and `s` are just user-defined variable names, they're not part of the awk language.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest you should mention that relies on undefined behavior per POSIX so it'll only work on some awks. The issue is that POSIX says NF will be populated in the END section but says nothing about $0, $1, $4, etc. so in some awks those will retain the value of the last record read but in other awks they'll be null. Any awk could do anything else they want with them too, of course, but that's the only 2 behaviors Ive come across in the wild.